# Angular 7 Template implement time issue

Tags: css, html, angular7, adminlte

i create one site in angular 7.i implement adminLTE theme but issue is `login and register` page have use different `css` and `dashboard` use different `css`.

so how can i put different css for both so there is no conflict.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Angular AdminLTE</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body hold-transition>
  <app-root>Loading ...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

and also `body` have different `class for login,register and dashboard` so how can i also use related class to its component

Please anyone can help me to out this.